# Can I add a NuGet package as a runtime dependency?

Tags: c#, .net

I Have a .NET class library (no core or std) and I would like to add a NuGet package as a runtime dependency. With runtime dependency i mean i do not like to add the package as a normal reference, since my project does not use this package. I however DO need all the dlls in the package to be copied to the output folder, because i need them at runtime.

'Why?'
Because i am working with a plugin-based model.

Comment: What is the undesired effect of adding the NuGet package to your project as usual? If your code doesn't use the assembly, it won't get loaded at all.

Comment: Your project doesn't use that dependency, but your project needs them at runtime? "Need" and "use" isn't that the same?

Comment: you could do that with `Assembly.LoadFrom` but keep in mind, that if your dependencies don't implement interfaces you have references to, you're going to rely heavily on reflection.

Comment: @marcofo88 The undesired effect is that the project can access the nuget package, whilst it should not be able to. I kinda want to add nuget packages as if everything in them had the scope internal and would not be accessible.

Comment: @OlegI Yeah i need them at runtime. I load my plugin at runtime, then that plugin will load the dependency. therefore i need the dependency at runtime, but the project does not use it. does that make sense?

Comment: @PatrickBeynio I'm already using LoadFrom

Comment: so your actual question is how to get the packets at runtime? if so take a look at [NuGet Server API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/api/overview)

Comment: @sommmen If you don't want the package to be referenced by the project, perhaps you could create another project that only holds the NuGet packages and reference that project. This way packages would not be directly accessible, but still copied to the bin folder (with .Net Core).

Comment: @PatrickBeynio No, i dont want to fetch the packages at runtime. I gues i want what 'ReferenceOutputAssembly' set to false does for nuget packages; https://peterdaugaardrasmussen.com/2019/01/13/c-make-the-build-of-one-project-depend-upon-another-project-without-creating-a-reference/

Comment: @marcofo88 hmm.. I've seen something like that somehwere else as well, where they use a project purely for compositioning of various packages. Although that is not really the answer im looking for its one idea.

Comment: Same Problem here. Compilation time of a plug-in solution is about 3 times worse because dozens of runtime dependency NuGet packages only needed by a single plug-in are included in _every_ plug-in project that depends on this plug-in. Of course the DLL is required at runtime, but from dependent plug-ins point of view this is opaque. We need an **equivalet of the CopyLocal option in assembly references for NuGet packages**. It propagates through project references also when the publish project does _not_ have a direct refernece to the assembly.